# How to open right to left menu slide bar in android

Tags: java, android

I am very new in android and I am excited to implement right to left menu bar animation, But I don't have any idea how can I implement it in my code.

Please provide a good tutorial or method how to implement in my code (activity class).

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to this [Sliding Menu Bar](https://www.google.co.in/#q=How+to+open+right+to+left+menu+slide+bar+in+android)

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu